# CMS Pages in Database .htaccess configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-management-system

In my CMS I store all pages in a database. If you request a page currently it works like this:

1. Requested URI: `www.xyz.com/site.html`
2. .htaccess: mod_rewrite creates: `/index.php?q=site`
3. index.php: Looks up in Database for the entry `site`.

To clean up the URLs I like to have URLS like this: `www.xyt.com/about/site.html` or `www.xyt.com/about/groups/groups.html`

In my Database is an entry for every Page called `owner` which represents the Parent Site.

The Problem for me is that the number of 'folders' is not fixed.
So i thought I should Change `www.xyt.com/about/site.php` to `/index.php?q=about-site` in the .htaccess and than write a PHP function which finds the site `site` with the Parent `about`

What would be the RewriteRule?
I that a good way or is there an other (better) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `foo/bar/about/site/etc.html` to `index.php?q=foo-bar-about-site-etc` is **much more difficult** with mod_rewrite than it is with PHP. Just do this in php, get the `$_GET['q']` variable and explode the string into an array or something using the `/` flags. It's also better this way because you'll know for sure that the `/` characters are reserved and you won't end up having to resolve stuff like `/foo-bar/about/site`. The rules would look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! That works well for me. I also added `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?q=$1 [L]` to process a `/` instead of `.html`. Can you just add a short Explanation of why you added the first rule?